# iPhone : Does not getting proper output while converting NSString into NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to convert NSString into NSDate.

So I tried following code :

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

    NSString *checkInDate = lblCheckIn.text;
    NSString *checkOutDate = lblCheckOut.text;
```

Here I am getting following output.

```
    NSLog(@"\nCheckIn Date : %@\nCheckOut Date : %@",checkInDate,checkOutDate);
    // CheckIn Date : 26-10-2011
    // CheckOut Date : 29-10-2011
```

Now I want to convert this NSString into NSDate with `dd-MM-yyyy` formate.

```
    NSDate *checkOut = [formatter dateFromString:checkOutDate];
    NSDate *checkIn = [formatter dateFromString:checkInDate];
    [formatter release];
```

But I got following output.

```
    NSLog(@"\nCheck In : %@\nCheck Out : %@",checkIn,checkOut);
    // Check In : 2011-10-25 18:30:00 +000
    // Check Out : 2011-10-28 18:30:00 +000
```

What could be wrong ?

Comment: I think you should set the NSDateFormatter with a bit more "configuration" in order to get the NSDate you want. Also if you just want the date like the first NSLog of NSStrings, use it like that, with NSStrings, if you store it in CoreData or something, when you retrieve it, just format it again and it should do the trick, hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are in +5:30 timezone..
Nothing wrong with your code. Its only printing the time in GMT timezone.

Comment: yes I am in +5:30 timezone. But from my code it should give output like 26-10-2011.

Comment: No, NSDate always gives time in GMT timezone.. Simply try to log current time.  `NSLog(@"%@",[NSDate date]);`. It will print time in GMT format.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[formatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSString *checkInDate =@"26-10-2011";
NSString *checkOutDate =@"29-10-2011";
NSDate *checkOut = [formatter dateFromString:checkOutDate];
NSDate *checkIn = [formatter dateFromString:checkInDate];

    [formatter release];
```